# Build link to Document from Task Completion Email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, tasks

Working with two SharePoint 2013 workflows, I am trying to build a link back to the document from the Task Completion workflow that runs during the document workflow.

On the Document, I have a workflow that "starts a task process" that goes to multiple people, assigning a task to each.  As each completes their task, I would like to notify the Person that created the document of the comments that were entered.

I don't see a method of doing this from this workflow, so I've created one for the task that sends an email if the task is marked completed.  I'm able to grab the feedback, and create a link to the Task ([%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]), but I can't get a link back to the document the task was created for.  I'm not even sure I'm getting the right person to notify.

Is there a way to get the person I need to notify, and create a link back to the document?